# Target Facebook ads on people who like certain pages (for which I'm not the owner)

Tags: advertising, facebook, social-media

Let's say I sell fountain pens (just an example).

I might have many potential customers among people who like the Facebook page "WeLoveFountainPens" or "MontBlanc Facebook page" (famous pen manufacturers).

But I'm not the owner of these Facebook pages (it could be a competitor for example).

Can I start a Facebook advertisement campaign **targeted on the audience of people who like "WeLoveFountainPens" and "MontBlanc"** Facebook pages ?

This would generate high conversion rates, and would make people who advertise happy, is there an option for this in Facebook?

*Note: All I've found is creating an audience with **interests**, but this is too broad, and I cannot find my specific market niche in it.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't target this way. The only way Facebook allows to target people connected to specific pages, is if you are the owner/admin of those pages.

[image]

Basically, you only get the above options to chose from.

So, instead of targeting people connected to specific pages, you could instead target people based on demographics, interest and behaviours and additionally add exclusions and to narrow down potential customers.

Without knowing your exact niche, I'll pick up your fountain pen example. I'm adding high income people in an area which I want to market to, then I'll narrow it down further to only add Men between 25 and 61, with a net income of above 75k Pounds which must match a specific set of criteria:

[image]

This leaves me with mostly a handful of people, but on the other hand I believe these will have a higher than average conversion rate, so I can crank up the daily spend. I will rinse and repeat the process to test out different audience groups with different ad-copies to find an optimal set of audiences and ads with high conversion rates which run profitable.